# React router Link absolute path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a a static menu which can be found on all sides.
This menu contains the following routes:

```js
<div className="layout-main">
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/orders/:id" exact component={OrderPage}/>
      <Route path="/orders" exact component={OrdersPage}/>
  </Switch>
</div>
```

The links in the side drawer looks like this:

```js
<NavLink to='/'>Dashboard</Navlink>
<NavLink to='orders'>Orders</Navlink>
```

When I am e.g. on page `/orders/3` and I press the NavLink **Orders**, the page `/orders/orders` is rendered. My goal is to display the normal `/orders` route.

What would be an appropriate solution (the menu should be kept global)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Redirect to `/orders` instead of `orders` in your link.

`orders` without the `/` is a relative link and will simply update the last part of your url. This type of link is useful for same page navigation.

Comment: oh my god. thank you! i swear i wouldve been on this for way longer if it wasnt for this answer