# React router link - how to navigate to absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const Button = () => {
  <Link to="SOME_S3_URL"/>
   <button>Go to S3 URL</button>
  </Link>
}
```

When I click it, it's not working.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Assuming you are routing to a url outside of your app, use an anchor tag and `href`

Comment: @Andrew I'm creating a reusable button, so I can't use anchor tag

Comment: Absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character, but it looks like you are trying to link to a URL outside the app, you will need to use a regular anchor tag for this. `react-router-dom` only links to internal pages rendered by the router. What is an ***actual*** target path value you are trying to use? `"SOME_S3_URL"` isn't very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130162/react-router-link-absolute-path

Comment: If you are routing outside of your app, you cannot use `react-router-dom`. That library is only for SPA "fake" routing

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do so as is; the `Link` component renders an anchor element, something fundamentally different than a button element.

If you need to use your reusable button, something you can do is:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const Button = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (<button onClick={() => navigate("SOME_S3_URL")}>Go to S3 URL</button>);
}
```

Comment: My answer targets v6, `useNavigate` replaces `useHistory` from v5.

Comment: It's pretty common to wrap a button in a link if you want a link that *looks like* a button. It's not great, but it isn't uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `SOME_S3_URL` is referring to an URL to Amazon S3, which in that case, is outside of your application.

So you should use a normal `<a/>` instead since `<Link />` is designed for internal navigation.

As for your comment about "creating a reusable button", you just apply CSS to the `<a />` element so that it will look like a button. This is a common practice used by multiple popular UI libraries like MUI and Chakra UI.

Comment: I tried to use <a> tag, but it just redirect me to path `/`

Comment: What's the exact value of `SOME_S3_URL`?